How can I convert code to synkron in Delphi
Anyone with experience of TTMSFNCCloudMicrosoftOutlookMail in FNC CloudPack from TMSData ?
Background:
The component it self is working fine. I could send email in half a day to OutLook Azure. But it rely on asynkron so my program continue immediately. An event will be called when email is sent successfully.
And this don't fit well with the logic I have so far.
Depending on settings either normal SMTP on local network is used or SendGrid API. Both use synkron or blocking.
So this OutLook Azure is the third way of emailing.
The calling code should of course not be aware of if blocking or nonblocking is used. So my only idea is to have 2 methods.
Send and SendWait and call one of them dependingon use case. Both choose the email solution of these 3.
So my question:
How can I implement SendWait with TTMSFNCCloudMicrosoftOutlookMail that use nonblocking mode and convert that to blocking ?
Internally the component call Synchronize so the background thread is waiting.
Using TEvent.WaitFor seems not work. I suppose main thread and background thread is waiting for each other
I don't believe it matters but Delphi 11.3 is used for this
I try this code
function TATMail.SendWait(const aReceiver, aSender, aReplyTo, aCc, aSubject,
  aBody, aAttachments: string; out AErrorMessage: string): Boolean;
var
  sErrorMessage: String;
  bSuccess: Boolean;
  oEvent: TEvent;
begin
  oEvent := TEvent.Create;
  try
    oEvent.ResetEvent;
    if GetSystemConfig.SendMailUsingSendGridRestApi then
      SendMailUsingSendGridApi(aReceiver, aSender, aReplyTo, aCc, aSubject, aBody, aAttachments,

        procedure(const AMessage: string; ASuccess: Boolean)
        begin
          sErrorMessage := AMessage;
          bSuccess := ASuccess;
          oEvent.SetEvent;
        end)
    else if GetSystemConfig.SendMailUsingMSOutlook365 then
    begin
      SendCloudMail(aReceiver, aReplyTo, aCc, aSubject, aBody, aAttachments,

        procedure(const AMessage: string; ASuccess: Boolean)
        begin
          sErrorMessage := AMessage;
          bSuccess := ASuccess;
          oEvent.SetEvent;
        end)
    end
    else
      SendMail(aReceiver, aSender, aReplyTo, aCc, aSubject, aBody, aAttachments,

        procedure(const AMessage: string; ASuccess: Boolean)
        begin
          sErrorMessage := AMessage;
          bSuccess := ASuccess;
          oEvent.SetEvent;
        end);

    if oEvent.WaitFor(50000) = wrSignaled then
    begin
      if bSuccess then
        GuiDialog.ShowMessage('Email sent successfully!')
      else
        GuiDialog.ShowMessage('Failed to send email.');
    end
    else
      GuiDialog.ShowMessage('Timeout occurred while sending email.');
  finally
    Result := bSuccess;
    oEvent.Free;
  end;
end;

I expect WaitFor to be signalled when oEvent.SetEvent is called. That never happen as component internally use Synchronize.
I want to avoid the famous ProcessMessages.

You need to periodically call CheckSynchronize. Something like while oEvent.WaitFor(100) <> wrSignaled do CheckSynchronize(50); and then adapt to your logic (if you need some final timeout, you will have to time it separately)

Ah ok. Thanks for the answer
